What does "self-sacrificed" mean?
Wrestler Kevin Von Erich was body-slammed onto the concrete floor
by Harley Race and is slowly crawling back into the ring:

Commentator: He's starting to come up, slowly but surely.
He crawls up. Kevin Von Erich. Unbelievable. What this man
has been through. He's seen it all. He's...Well, he's self-sacrificed.

What does "self-sacrificed" mean?

Questions that could be answered by a dictionary are off-topic here. What do you think it means, and why do you doubt what you think? I also note that this looks like a transcript of a live commentary. Extemporaneous speech is not worth scrutinising as even native speakers make mistakes. The tense of "self-sacrificed" is unusual as it sounds like a verb in the past tense, while we normally use "self-sacrificing" as an adjective or say "he's sacrificed himself" to denote the action. Either way, a dictionary will see you straight on this.

I think the usage is so wildly non-standard that asking the question is understandable.

In English, basically, any noun can be made into a verb, i.e. verbed.
So, self-sacrifice is a noun and this author has made it into a verb and used the simple past to refer to that action.
It means  the wrestler has made a self-sacrifice of himself.
The commentator could have said: He has sacrificed himself but there one would generally say to what.
In these "wrestling" matches, commentators often exaggerate. It sounds like maybe he means for this particular match, the wrestler decided to lose.
Merriam Webster:
Noun: self-sacrifice
: sacrifice of oneself or one's interest for others or for a cause or ideal

Verbing weirds language, as a wise philosopher once said.

The phrase "He's self-sacrificed" is an impromptu coinage by the announcer, from the noun self-sacrifice, which refers to someone enduring hardship or deprivation in order that things be better for someone else. It's not clear that the announcer is familiar with how the noun is normally used, for how does the standard meaning apply here?  Who is the wrestler sacrificing for?

Working Brits who get sick can get 7 days paid leave by simply calling in and telling their employer. After that they need a document from their doctor. This used to be called a 'medical certificate'. In the initial period they are said to be (or to have!) self-certified. I think the wrestler (and commentator?) are American though
